# Did all the midyanim die?

Tags: gentiles, army-military-war, shoftim--book-of, mattos, yishmael

In the war with Midyon, the Torah infers all of their men were killed, and girls not of mature age were spared

Now if they were all killed, how do they appear in Shoftim as being the oppressors of Bnei Yisroel for 6 years ( שופטים 6:1-8)

Did all of the non mature girls of מדין get released and then married other בני ישמעאל/קטורה and that’s how the nation was revived?

Comment: If so this means the midyan in shoftim was only בשם Midyan, and not a תולדה of מדין בן אברהם

Comment: I've seen suggested that is was only a local "brach" of the broader Midianite people (who as Yishmael-like nomads could well have been widely dispersed)